# Simplify SQL to run query for each artist only

Tags: python, loops

This is the query:

```
for artist_id in artist_ids:
    params = {
         "id": artist_id
    }
    sql = """SELECT * FROM artists WHERE id = :id"""
    db_value = db.session.execute(sql, params).fetchall()
```

What I am trying to do is to rewrite the code without query by calling all artist IDs in a single query. How to do that?

Comment: So you want your single SQL query to return the rows for all artist_ids? Instead of n consecutive calls?

Comment: @Sri, yes, sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string into the proper text with the `join` function, then insert that into the SQL query string:

```
artist_ids_parameter = ",".join([str(i) for i in artist_ids])
sql = f"""SELECT * FROM artists WHERE id IN ({artist_ids_parameter})"""
```

Comment: `[SQL: 'SELECT * FROM artist WHERE id IN ({artist_ids_parameter})']`. `^` symbol points at `{`.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your list to a tuple.

```
artist_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sql = """SELECT * FROM artists WHERE id IN {}""".format(tuple(artist_ids))
```

Comment: `[SQL: 'SELECT * FROM artist WHERE id IN (121,)'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)`

Comment: Ah, that is a fair point. A tuple with one element will have a comma in it. You can refer to the below solution by @LTheriault. Alternatively, you can check if the length is 1 and instead of doing in, use equals